# How to hide update dialog box when app is running for the first time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `upgrader` package for showing dialog box telling user to update the app. Now, I don't want it to pop up when user is opening the app for the first time. How should I achieve this? Is there a field where I can put some kind of condition which can be true/false and accordingly it will show me the box?

Comment: how about wrapping on `if(show)MyWidget`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save the value. for example, you can set an `integer` value with the name `isTheFirstTime` and set it to 0 which you can consider as a `false`.
and when you run the app for the first time it will check this value which is `false` and put this condition before your widget:

```
if(theValueYouChecked){ yourWidget }
```

At the first time, `theValueYouChecked` will be `false`, set the value in your dialog function in the shared preference to `true` so that when you run the app any time except for the first time you will get `true` so your widget will appear.